# How to subtract rows within groups of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a multi-index Pandas dataframe, df2, I want to compute the difference of each row from the row above within each category.

```
import pandas as pd
inner = ('a','b','c')
cols = ('A','B','C','D')
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,4), index=inner, columns=cols)
df2=pd.concat([df1,df1],keys=['X','Y'])
```

df2:

```
                A      B             C         D
X   a   -0.391804   -0.307916   -0.265643   -0.222193
    b   -0.142498   -1.389972   1.060328    1.207945
    c   1.156881    1.596382    0.620923    0.592739
Y   a   -0.391804   -0.307916   -0.265643   -0.222193
    b   -0.142498   -1.389972   1.060328    1.207945
    c   1.156881    1.596382    0.620923    0.592739
```

**Here is what I tried:**

```
df2.groupby(level=[0]).apply(lambda x: df2.loc[x.index[:-1]-df2.loc[x.index[1:]]])
```

But this will get a wrong result dataframe with three-leves of indices.

```
             A           B          C           D
X   X   a   -0.391804   -0.307916   -0.265643   -0.222193
        b   -0.142498   -1.389972   1.060328    1.207945
Y   Y   a   -0.391804   -0.307916   -0.265643   -0.222193
        b   -0.142498   -1.389972   1.060328    1.207945
```

Comment: if you `groupby` on all levels of your index, each group will only have a 1 row in it, so your results of all `NaNs` makes sense.

Comment: it'd help to understand what you're trying to accomplish if you posted the expected output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't group by all level of your index b/c then each group will only have 1 row, and there's nothing to subtract. Also, using non-random data (the subtraction isn't intuitive) let's changed your example a bit:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    data={'A': np.arange(8) ** 2, 'B': np.arange(8) ** 0.5},
    index=pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([list('XY'), list('abcd')])
)
df
#       A         B
# X a   0  0.000000
#   b   1  1.000000
#   c   4  1.414214
#   d   9  1.732051
# Y a  16  2.000000
#   b  25  2.236068
#   c  36  2.449490
#   d  49  2.645751
```

So if we only group along a *subset* of the index levels, we can use the `shift` method of the dataframe to get a rolling difference within each group:

```
df.groupby(level=[0]).transform(lambda g: g.shift(-1) - g)

#       A         B
# X a   1  1.000000
#   b   3  0.414214
#   c   5  0.317837
#   d NaN       NaN
# Y a   9  0.236068
#   b  11  0.213422
#   c  13  0.196262
#   d NaN       NaN
```